# Start linux command with "su" and inline variable

Tags: linux, unix, firefox, ksh

I'm trying to create mozilla profile for another user from command line using su.

When I'm trying from X, this will work.

```
su myuser -c 'mozilla -CreateProfile newprofile'
```

But my goal is to embed this to a script and it will execute only in command line mode.
If I try this, from a command line, It also works:

```
DISPLAY=1.0 mozilla -CreateProfile newprofile
```

The question is how to embed "DISPLAY" variable in "su" command, cause this fails:

```
su myuser -c 'DISPLAY=1.0 mozilla -CreateProfile newprofile'
```

Comment: Why is "linux" in the title if you say you are running SCO Unix?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this:

```
su myuser -c 'export DISPLAY=\"1.0\"; mozilla -CreateProfile newprofile'
```

This should really be posted on superuser.com

Try that variant by escaping the quotes in the variable DISPLAY...

Comment: Yes, I've tryed it. It fails too.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
su sh -c 'DISPLAY=1.0  echo $DISPLAY'
```

what exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Maybe becouse of my OS - SCO Unix. Errors are only some perl warnings from 'locale', but I've got them also in X mode, so this is not the reason. Mozilla comand finishes, but without creating the profile.

Comment: SCO Unix? Respect.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
su myuser -c "sh -c 'DISPLAY=1.0 mozilla -CreateProfile newprofile'"
```

Comment: No it fails too.

Comment: And what does complain?

Comment: It does not complain. it finishes cleanly, but profile directory is not created. Never mind, I solved the problem. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
su - -c 'DISPLAY=1.0 mozilla -CreateProfile newprofile' myuser
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TEMPXAUTH=$(xauth nlist) su -c 'xauth nmerge <<< "$TEMPXAUTH" && mozilla -CreateProfile newprofile'
```

A temporary file would work too.